# Persistent animation for RecyclerView childs

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-animation, persistent, measurement

I have a RecyclerView with setReverseLayout to **true** (chat layout).
[image: chat screen downloaded from web]

Say i click on the item at *2* position (remember its layout is reversed) and call

> **notifyItemChanged(2[position])**

In **onBindViewHolder** i make some views visible on that clicked item, so its height will change, and when **RecyclerView** would *measure* its children it would realize that it should move some items around to make that items height change appear engaging )). **DefaultItemAnimator** takes care of it, but it moves all children below *"U are??? Omg thank u"* item downwards. As my layout is reversed i would like all items above that clicked item to animate and move upwards. Is it possible??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigating **RecyclerView** and **LinearLayoutManager** codes , you should simply call

> setStackFromEnd(boolean stackFromEnd)

with true. )

Answer (score 0):

try overriding animateChange() of DefaultItemAnimator

you also have to set this new item animator to recycler view

Comment: viewholders passed to DefaultItemAnimator are already wrong ones(below items), and in processing of this animations(pre-, post- layout) **animateMove()** is called not animateChange.